# How to create a multipart form post request handler in vertx

Tags: java, post, httprequest, multipartform-data, vert.x

Hello I am using  vertx in java on a standalone app to read a port in my web app. I want to get the post data from a form.
My web app has a form with a post method that  I am looking to read. 
My logic is

1. Create verticle
2. Create http Server
3. Create handler request ( it does   not take all the parameters in my
   code)
4. Listen to httpServer
5. Expect Multipart Request in Handler
6. Multimap and get form attributes

I dont know what I am missing , I am new to vertx .

For some reason I  cannot post code on here.

My code: 
https://pastebin.com/A1hjXFb6

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your HTML form is having `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute.

Then in your vertx code:

```
public class loginLogic extends AbstractVerticle {

    //Vertx vertx;
    private HttpServer httpServer = null;

    @Override
        public void start() {
            Router router = Router.router(vertx);
            router.route().handler(BodyHandler.create().setUploadsDirectory("uploads"));
            router.post("/form").handler(ctx -> {
                  ctx.response().putHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                  ctx.response().setChunked(true);
                  for (FileUpload f : ctx.fileUploads()) {
                    System.out.println("f");
                    ctx.response().write("Filename: " + f.fileName());
                    ctx.response().write("\n");
                    ctx.response().write("Size: " + f.size());
                  }

                  ctx.response().end();
            });
            vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which library do I need to implement Router router = Router.router(vertx);

Comment: Do I need to enable uploads?
All I want is to get the post data from a form

Comment: Router is part of vertx `io.vertx.ext.web.Router`. You don't need to enable anything, just set the upload path.

Comment: that is not what i need to do, I just need to use a java class in a native app to read an html form.